# How to extend an object while ignoring null values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say for example I have an object of

```
var user = { 
    "Name": "Dan", 
    "Age": 27, 
    "Hobbies": null 
};
```

which I would like to merge onto the following base object so that my user object will have all the required properties

```
var base = { 
    "Name": null, 
    "Height": null, 
    "Age": null, 
    "Hobbies": [
        { "Name": "Tennis", "Location": null },
        { "Name": "Football", "Location": null },
        { "Name": "Rugby", "Location": null }
    ]
};
```

The easiest way to merge to the two objects would be to extend the base object with the user object as follows

```
$.extend(true, base, user);
```

which would modify the base object to be

```
{ 
    "Name": "Dan", 
    "Height": null, 
    "Age": 27, 
    "Hobbies": null
};
```

My question would be how can I get the extend method to not override null values? For example, in this instance, how can I still obtain a list of hobbies if the users hobby list is null so I end up with the following

```
{ 
    "Name": "Dan", 
    "Height": null, 
    "Age": 27, 
    "Hobbies": [
        { "Name": "Tennis", "Location": null },
        { "Name": "Football", "Location": null },
        { "Name": "Rugby", "Location": null }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may use `undefined` as value which will be ignored by `jQuery.extend`.

```
var user = { "Name": "Dan", 
             "Age:" 27, 
             "Hobbies": undefined 
           };
$.extend(true, base, user);
```

Comment: same as @Vega. +1 clever...never thought about this. :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works in jQuery (tested with v1.11.2). Undefined values are not copied over. See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ . Quote: "Undefined properties are not copied... For needs that fall outside of this behavior, write a custom extend method instead, or use a library like lodash"