# Is there a way to keep $.extend from propagating null valued properties to the target

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the line of executed code where a list of defaultOptions in the method is set
 to a bunch of null values with a few exceptions...

```
var passedOptions = $.extend({},defaultOptions, configOptions);

defaultOptions =
{ 
    "method":"POST",
    "url":"",
    "params":null,
    "data":null,
    "headers":null,
    "xsrfHeaderName":null,
    "xsrfCookieName":null,
    "transformRequest":null,
    "transformResponse":null,
    "cache":false,
    "timeout":null,
    "withCredentials":false,
    "reqsponseType":null
}

configOptions = 
 {
    "url":"someurl/blahblah",
    "data": "username":"me@email.com",
    "email":"me@email.com"
 }
```

Here is what I want passedOptions to look like

```
passOptions = 
{
   "method":"POST",
   "url":"someurl/blahblah",
   "data": "username":"me@email.com",
   "email":"me@email.com"
   "cache" : false,
   "withCredentials" : false
}
```

Basically a combination of the two but where the properties with null values are NOT copied to the target.  Is this possible??

Comment: ideally jQuery should ignore the null and undefined keys (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) but it doesn't, probably because of a bug http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12212

Comment: That ticket seems to read that it will ignore the arguments to $.extend such that if configOptions was null itself then it would ignore it, but I'm thinking of the deeper implementation that it ignores null sub-properties in any objectN's to the final target so the target is a merge of the two objects less all null or undefined valued properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do it manually:

```
var passedOptions={};
for(var i in defaultOptions){
    if(defaultOptions[i] != null){
        passedOptions[i]=defaultOptions[i];
    }
}
for(var i in configOptions){
    if(configOptions[i] != null){
        passedOptions[i]=configOptions[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought of that, just didn't know if there was something native in jquery that would do that for me

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer and although it doesn't ignore null values it does allow for merging objects down to a target while ignoring properties with undefined values.  Replacing all the nulls with undefined worked.

[How to extend an object while ignoring null values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687550/how-to-extend-an-object-while-ignoring-null-values)